# Query fails sometimes on casting error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, hive

I have a query that can run on the same data set, and sometimes it fails and sometimes it succeeds

The query is generated by hive metadata service, and I can't modify it.

This is a simplified version of the query:

```
select
    "TBLS"."TBL_ID",
    "FILTER0"."PART_ID",
    "TBLS"."TBL_NAME",
    "FILTER0"."PART_KEY_VAL"
from
    "PARTITIONS"
inner join "TBLS" on
    "PARTITIONS"."TBL_ID" = "TBLS"."TBL_ID"
    and "TBLS"."TBL_NAME" = 'test_table_int'
inner join "PARTITION_KEY_VALS" "FILTER0" on
    "FILTER0"."PART_ID" = "PARTITIONS"."PART_ID"
where
    cast("FILTER0"."PART_KEY_VAL" as decimal(21, 0)) = 1
```

When I spin up a new database, and populate the relevant tables, this is how the whole data looks like (querying without any filters):

[image]

and running the query above will return a single row (the one with `PART_KEY_VAL` = 1)

the problem starts after I run some automated tests that write to those tables. I couldn't find any pattern, I just run a few complicate tests that write to those tables

Now if I populate those tables again, the data looks similar:

[image]

but running the query above will result in:

> SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "c"

for some reason, the value "c" is being cast to decimal and it fails, even though the same query on the same data was working earlier

what could be the reason for this behavior?

---

for reference, here is where the query is generated, but I simplified it a bit above: https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/rel/release-3.1.2/standalone-metastore/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/MetaStoreDirectSql.java#L1289-L1339

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: It's impossible that Postgres ever converted `c` to a number. If that query worked "previously" you apparently only had numbers in that column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, there is also a filter on `"TBLS"."TBL_NAME"`, so if that filter is applied first, that column have only numerical values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that for some reason postgres stops using the index on the column "TBL_NAME".

when the index is used, the table is filtered first, and the remaining values are all ints.
but when the index is not used, the cast will happen on all the rows, and will fail on the strings.

as a workaround, I set `enable_seqscan = false`, and that forces postgres to use the index, but that is not a long term solution.

I opened a bug on hive with a more detailed explanation of the problem:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-23576